# Have Postgresql accept 1 and 0 as true and false for boolean

Tags: postgresql

I have a large file of dumped sql data to load in to postgresl (600mb+). In that dump, fields that are boolean true and false are expessed as 1 and 0 without quotes. Trying to load them in to postgresql, results in complains as it doesnt know how to cast them.

Loading like this...

```
psql --disable-triggers -1 -f /foo/bar/dump.sql
```

Due to the large amount of data and the sprinkling of boolean fields in the - regexing through to replace them with true/false appropriately has proved impractical.

After much googling i havent been able to find a way to have postgresql accept that = true and 0 = false for the duration of this data load. It seems simple enough, but its apparently not!

Hopefully someone knows exactly how to nail it and can help me out!

Answer (score 10):

Digging in to the dark magic of postgresql, i discovered that the integer to boolean cast can be changed from an exlicit to an automatic coersion. Then changed back when done...

```
update pg_cast set castcontext='a' where casttarget = 'boolean'::regtype;
```

Then load with pg_dump.

When done, set back the casting to its default with...

```
update pg_cast set castcontext='e' where casttarget = 'boolean'::regtype;
```

**Important note: don't do this unless you know what it involves.   The catalogs aren't guaranteed to be compatible version to version, and something that's safe(ish) to do now could be quite bad to do in a future version, or not work at all.**

Comment: I tried this on postgres v15.2, to import SQL from another db vendor, but it didn't work for me. The pg_cast query above went through fine but 0 & 1 were still rejected for booleans. Maybe I did something wrong.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to accept 0 and 1 as boolean, your best bet is probably to create the table with the column defined as `smallint` with a `CHECK (colname >= 0 AND colname <= 1)` condition.

After import you can `ALTER TABLE` to change the type to `boolean` and provide a `USING` term to do the type conversion.

Alternately, use a more flexible data-loader, like [pgloader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader), Pentaho Kettle, Talend Studio, etc, rather than trying to get `COPY` to accept the data.

I do think that accepting 0/1 as false/true would be desirable at least for the `CSV` mode of `COPY`. If you submit a patch I expect it'll probably get accepted.

Comment: the dump is all inserts, so i was hoping to use some sort of one line cast declairation or something so postgresql has a way to convert from int to bool.

Comment: @Dean Don't think so, probably not even by messing with the system catalogs directly, since the `bool_in` function will be consuming the value. Create the table with an integer column then change it after the import.

Comment: Digging in to the dark magic of postgresql, i discovered that the integer to boolean cast can be changed from an exlicit to an automatic coersion. Then changed back when done...

   update pg_cast set castcontext='a' where casttarget = 'boolean'::regtype;

Then load the pgdump. When done, set it back with...

   update pg_cast set castcontext='e' where casttarget = 'boolean'::regtype;

Comment: @Dean Exactly so. **Please** don't put that in production applications, etc, though; the catalogs aren't guaranteed to be compatible version to version, and something that's safe(ish) to do now could be quite bad to do in a future version, or not work at all. I'm a little surprised that making the cast implicit worked, actually, I expected `bool_in` to be called directly and to fail.

Comment: My answer would have been to change the cast.  Please upgrade your comment to an answer.

Comment: @Dean Peter's right - that's certainly an appropriate answer, with a "don't do this unless you know what it involves" note, anyway.

Comment: @CraigRinger please check my edit there

Comment: It is a pitty that you cannot add a custom implicite cast for those combinations where you have a explicite one in the catalog. We would really like to have 0 + 1 allowed to compare booleans as this is widely used in existing code when porting it from oracle or even mssql.

Answer (score 1):

I had some CSV files exported from Microsoft Access, which outputs True as 1 and False as 0. I imported them to Postgres using [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) but it converted all the 1's to false. So wound up using [pgloader](https://pgloader.io/) to import those tables - it handles the 1's and 0's automatically.

I'm on Windows, so had to use the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) to run pgloader.

Make a file called `csv.load`:

```
LOAD CSV
    FROM 'entity.csv'
    INTO postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/DATABASE?TABLENAME
    WITH
        skip header = 1,
        fields optionally enclosed by '"',
        fields escaped by double-quote,
        fields terminated by ','
;
```

Then run pgloader -

```
pgloader csv.load
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and after reading the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) saw that it does accept 0's and 1's but only as strings! So I ran `ALTER TABLE [TABLE NAME] ALTER COLUMN [COLUMN NAME] TYPE TEXT` and from there cast to Boolean! (In my case I also had to drop the default first and add it back in after).

Answer (score -1):

[image]

alter table test alter done type integer using case when done=true then 0 else 1 end;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/192247)